# how can I share link to messenger by opening messenger app, if I use facebook messenger sdk it shows

Tags: objective-c

Starting August 15, 2019, updated versions of the Messenger app will no longer support Share to Messenger SDK. Businesses and developers might need to make modifications to their app to trigger nativ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)messengerTapped:(id)sender{

NSURL *fbURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb-messenger://share?link=%@",_linkUrl]];


UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

[application openURL:fbURL options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success)  {

    if (success) {
         NSLog(@"Opened url");
    }


}];

}
```